# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
Class Card

    def initialize(suit, number)
        @suit = suit
        @number = number
    end
end
```

I am getting the error message:

```
/go_fish/lib/Card.rb:8 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Any suggestions or stuff I'm missing?

Comment: `class Card`, not `Class`....

Comment: also, I haven't voted to close this because although it is a simple typographical error, the fix is one that might prove useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is the first char in the first line. `class` should be lowercase...

```
class Card
  def initialize(suit, number)
    @suit = suit
    @number = number
  end
end
```

Furthermore you may want to follow common rules for coding styles in Ruby. To do so change the file name to `card.rb` (again lowercase), same with `require`. And it is common to indent with just two whitespace characters in Ruby files.

Comment: Why should the file name be `card.rb`?

Comment: Out of the same reason I suggested to use 2 whitespaces to indent the code, it is just common and best practice in the Ruby community.

Comment: Your wording of "should" was not clear enough to me. It sounded like it was a mistake to do otherwise.

Comment: Thank you...good lord can't believe I didn't notice that.  And thank you for the extra advice on coding styles.